# Why I can not reach this keycloak rest api end point?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve users list based on their roles. I have this role: ROLE_ADMIN. I would like to retrieve every user that have this role.

I try it with this endpoint:

`http://10.10.10.10:5555/auth/demo-realm/clients/e286a05c-6641-49c3-bb7c-ffe5dd2d8c66/roles/ROLE_ADMIN/users`

but it sends me back this:

> {
> "error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: [http://10.10.10.10:5555/auth/demo-realm/clients/e286a05c-6641-49c3-bb7c-ffe5dd2d8c66/roles/ROLE_ADMIN/users"](http://10.10.10.10:5555/auth/demo-realm/clients/e286a05c-6641-49c3-bb7c-ffe5dd2d8c66/roles/ROLE_ADMIN/users%22)
> }

I found the endpoint here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html under `"Return List of Users that have the specified role name"`.

I can reach these end points for example:

> http://10.10.10.10:5555/auth/realms/demo-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
>
> http://10.10.10.10:5555/auth/admin/realms/demo-realm/users

What did I miss? What makes this to not work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

To get the users associate with a given **Realm role** you need to call the endpoint:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/roles/<ROLE_NAME>/users
```

to get the users associate with a given **Client role** you need to call this endpoint:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/clients/<CLIENT_ID>/roles/<ROLE_NAME>/users
```

where `<CLIENT_ID>` is the `ID` from the client to which the `<ROLE_NAME>` belongs to.

Finally, to get the client `ID`, you can call this endpoint:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/clients?clientId=<ID_OF_CLIENT>
```

Note that the client `ID` is the unique `ID` generated by Keycloak, whereas `<ID_OF_CLIENT>` is the `Client ID` that you have given to your Keycloak client.