# Keycloak https auth page unable to acces

Tags: linux, https, authorization, keycloak

I generated selfsigned domain certificate and then started Keycloak:

```
docker run \
  --name keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.crt.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.key.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak \
  start-dev
```

But I can't access auth page `https://<IP>:8443/auth/`. There is always "Page not found" error.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no more `auth`. It is now called `admin`

Access page with: `https://<IP>:8443/admin/`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Keycloak 17 for the Quarkus distribution](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus):

> The new distribution introduces a number of breaking changes,
> including:
>
> - Configuring Keycloak has significantly changed
> - Quarkus is not an application server, but rather a framework to build applications
> - /auth removed from the default context path
> - Custom providers are packaged and deployed differently

Because of the third bullet point you are getting

> But I can't access auth page https://:8443/auth/. There is always
> "Page not found" error.

You can get around this issue with one of two solutions:

1. Use the previous endpoints, but now removing `/auth` from them or;
2. as pointed on in the documentation:

> By default, the new Quarkus distribution removes /auth from the
> context-path. To re-introduce the /auth use the http-relative-path
> build option. For example: bin/kc.[sh|bat] start-dev --http-relative-path /auth