# Keycloak API: How to change associated client roles of a composite role

Tags: keycloak, user-management

I want to change the **associated client roles** in my `admin-sso` role. I can change the associated realm roles **but not the client roles**.

Let's say I have a client role `realm-management` and I would like to add the role `manage-identity-provider` to the associated roles - how can I do it via. API?

I read the [Keycloak 11.0 API docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ5Mz.png) but don't find the right path.

I added a screenshot on how I can do it via admin UI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

From a high-level point of view you need to:

- Get admin access token;
- Get the `ID` of the `realm-management client`; [Endpoint GET /{realm}/clients](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getclients)
- Get the `ID` of the `admin-sso`; [Endpoint GET/realm/roles/{role-name}](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getrole)
- Get the information about the `manage-identity-providers`; [Endpoint GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getrole)
- Assign the role `manage-identity-providers` to `admin-sso`; [Endpoint POST /{realm}/roles-by-id/{role-id}/composites](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_addcomposites)

---

In case others are interested, I have uploaded a [bash script on my GitHub repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/Keycloak/blob/main/scripts/assignClientRoleToRealmRole) that (among others) takes a realm role and a client role and assigns the client role to the realm role. So basically it automatizes the steps that I am about to describe.

---

**Step-by-Step**

> I read the Keycloak 11.0 API docs but don't find the right path.

You need to call several endpoints from the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. In this answer, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm.

```bash
curl “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token” \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}” \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable named `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later use.

Now you need to get the `ID` of the client `realm-management`

```bash
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/clients?clientId=realm-management \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From the response extract the `ID` of the client, *e.g.,* `jq -r .[].id`. Let us say that you saved on a variable named `$ID_OF_CLIENT`.

Next you need to get the information about the role 'admin-sso':

```bash
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/roles/admin-sso \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From the response extract the role `id`, *e.g.,* `jq -r .id`. Let us say that you save that content in the a variable named `REALM_ROLE_ID`.

Next you need to get the information about the `manage-identity-providers` role as follows:

```bash
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/clients/$ID_OF_CLIENT/roles/manage-identity-providers \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

You will get a json response that you need to use in the next API call. For now, let us assume that you save that content in a variable named `$ROLE_JSON`.

Finally, you can now assign the `manage-identity-providers` role to the `admin-sso` role.

```bash
curl -X POST https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/roles-by-id/$REALM_ROLE_ID/composites \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     -d "[$ROLE_JSON]"
```

Comment: couldn't expect a better answer, cheers mate!

Comment: Thank you for the response; it also worked for me. This should have been a joke for simply upgrading the role.