# Update Realm json Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is there any API to pass values to update a keycloak realm's json after the realm is created ?

I am trying to pass a value to a realm dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any API to pass values to update a keycloak realm's json
> after the realm is created ?

Yes, you can find that, and several other endpoints, in the [Keycloak Admin Rest API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871).

To update the realm you can use the endpoint [PUT /{realm}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871).

---

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

You can get that information using the Keycloak Admin REST API; to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm.

```bash
curl “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token” \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}” \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To change the realm you can call the following:

```bash
curl -X PUT “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}” \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}” \
     -d "${THE_REALM_JSON}"
```

The `${THE_REALM_JSON}` will contain the new values that you want to change in the realm.